# Spring security saml2 SSO

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I have an application that is integrated with spring security seperated to two application.I want to get single sign on(SSO) with lowest cost and it compatible with spring security.

I am trying to integrate SAML, but i don't know if i can use a local IDP communicating with LDAP(CAS for example).

Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: An IdP just converts user information to SAML. Where it gets the user information from is up to the developer and where the data is stored. An IdP communicating with LDAP is one of the most common scenarios

Comment: Can I use CAS Server as an IdP  without online IdP ?

Comment: As long as your IDP supports SAML 2.0 WebSSO profile, you'll be fine whether it's deployed locally or on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback, can I find examples using CAS as a SAML2 identity provider.